# Hindi and Gujarati font show in textview in IOS(Swift)?

Tags: ios, swift

Webservice responce in diffrent diffrent language .Now I show it in textview with that language and with html tag that are apply it in.

Comment: What/Where is the problem?

Comment: responce of api in gujarati language .That responce I store data and convert it in htmlToAttributedString ,but after that gujarati language convert in english language character.

Comment: just parse it into the string and then store and use it.

Answer (score 0):

Just parse it as a `String` it will automatically appear in your component